# How to say 一〇年 in a sentence

Tags: readings, orthography, numbers

I see this structure a lot:

> まるで**一〇**年以上.......

What does the **一〇** mean and how do I pronounce it? Is it いちまる?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you find 〇 being used together with *kanji* numerals (一, 二, 三, ...) to signify "zero".

In horizontal writing it is more common to express numbers using Arabic numerals (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) — and Arabic numerals are often also used in vertical writing.

Here

> 一〇年以上 = 十年以上 = 10年以上
>   *jū nen ijō*
>   more than ten years